# "Install-Package WebRTC -Version 1.62.0.7" from NuGet doesn't work

Tags: nuget, webrtc

When I try to use WebRTC in my code, after installing it with NuGet, it crashes in the line WebRTC.Initialize(this.Dispatcher);.

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            //Initialization of WebRTC worker threads, etc
            try
            {
                WebRTC.Initialize(this.Dispatcher);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            } 
        }
```

If I try to open properties of References:OrgWebRtc in my project, Visual Studio 2017 shows nothing.
Is there some way to use NuGet for installing WebRTC, which works?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Havent foud a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Install-Package WebRTC –Version 1.54.2 worked for me.